# Oracle SQL Developer - Source does not have a runnable target While Create Function

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I am very new to Oracle. I am trying to create a user-defined function and when I debug or run the code from Oracle SQL Developer,  I get the error message '**Source does not have a runnable target**'.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION F_CONTENT ( ComponentID IN NUMBER) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS rtVal VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN

Select dbms_lob.substr( wm_concat(CONCAT(CONCAT(material , ' '), CONCAT( percentage , '%'))), 250, 1)   
INTO  rtVal From composition_component 
Where component_id = ComponentID;

RETURN  rtval;

END F_CONTENT;
```

Comment: Compile, close SQL Developer, start SQL Developer and try again.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and the 'Source..' error was gone. But I am getting this new one.Connecting to the database dgallery.
Executing PL/SQL: ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_DEBUG=TRUE
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '172.17.22.187', '56267' )
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1
This session requires DEBUG CONNECT SESSION and DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE user privileges.
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database dgallery.

Comment: Error message speaks for itself. You have to see to it that the user was granted the required privileges.

Comment: I fixed the errors. Thanks for the excellent solution, Rene.